# How to access your own services/factory in AngularJs boostrap

Tags: angularjs, cookies

In my application , there is a need to check for the authentication of the user which we usually store in the cookies (whether user is logged in or not). So, whenever a user hit a page (by navigating the url directly in address bar), we need to check first whether the cookie value is present or not. For that, we need to access one of our service which reads value from the cookie. But, where and how exactly I can inject my own services during bootstrap application.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    //Where to inject the dependencies of my own services here??
});
```

Comment: Exactly the same place as if you used `ng-app` - inside your `module` declaration

Comment: Say, if I wan to use one of my service named UserInfo, so where and how can I inject it so that I can use one of the function defined in that service?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the injector directly?

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var yourServie = angular.injector(["app"]).get('yourService');

    // Do something here with your service before bootstrapping

    angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    //Where to inject the dependencies of my own services here??
});
```

I don't have my code base in front of me but we do this with `$http` to make a request to the server to get configuration before we bootstrap.

Comment: $http is accessible but I don't know for some reasons, my services are not accessible. Do I need to introduce some providers or something else?